# mod_rewrite rule error when using /

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following RewriteRule in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^advanced-lift-truck?$ pub-listing-full.php?mag=1 [NC,L]
```

How could I modify this so that `.../advanced-lift-truck/` works, as well as `.../advanced-lift-truck`? (Note the `/` in the first version.)

I'm assuming I'll need a separate rule, but I've tried the following also:

```
RewriteRule ^advanced-lift-truck/?$ pub-listing-full.php?mag=1 [NC,L]
```

but this forwards me to `pub-listing-full.php` without the query string, and without any CSS/JS files loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the query string is missing, but you need to deal with all of your relative URLs in the links of your page. With the extra `/`, browsers assume the base URI to resolve any relative links (to stuff like style sheets and scripts) is `/advanced-lift-truck/`. Try adding this to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/" />
```